# Aggregate values in AppSync resolvers

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

In a live session, I expect brief bursts of traffic when a teacher presents a poll and a large portion of students respond with a (thumbs up/down) which we will route via AppSync to cumulate the sum and present to the teacher

I am planning to update the total rating (thumbs up/down) in a DynamoDB record. Any suggestions for solving it an optimal way using resolvers or lambda ?

Can resolvers/lambda persist data for a brief time and then write it to DynamoDB ?

Or is it possible to connect appsync to any other AWS Service to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly you are asking for some sort of queuing system that will hold the votes and write them all at once? If so that's not possible w appsync or lambdas due to their distributed nature. There are some tricks that can be used for some sort of semi persistence but thats not a good use case (more for caching the result of a complex lambda startup for ex). But I would not worry about that as DynamoDB can handle all your requests. You can use the [updateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD) query with SET to increment a count for example. There are some example of using SET on this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html).

Comment: I'm afraid that I might lose userId level votes by just aggregating in a single record. And for a brief spike in traffic (say 30K users), having two writes (one for updating the vote and one for persisting each vote of the user), would take a hit on scale and cost.